# Regular Expression Help NOT Contains

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I've been spinning my wheels for quite sometime.  I need a regular expression that matches the following conditions:

```
anytextherethatdoesNOTcontainDEVString@mail.mydomain.com
```

For example:

```
first.last@mail.mydomain.com //match
firstLast@mail.mydomain.com //match
name@mail.mydomain.com //match
dev.test@mail.mydomain.com //NON-match contains "dev" string case non-sensitive
dev@mail.mydomain.com //NON-match contains "dev" string case non-sensitive
```

Comment: `boolean matches = !regex.matches();`

Comment: For such a simple thing, why not simply use a simple string search? regex is for "complicated" patterns, but all you want to see if is the 3 characters "dev" are present or not. Regex for that is massive overkill.

Comment: The reason why I needed a REGEX is because I want the flexibility of changing the match/search string without having to recompile and redeploy the application.  Rather, I change the REGEX in a config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work (use it with the case insensitive flag):

```
 "^(?:(?!dev).)+@mail\.mydomain\.com$"
```

http://rubular.com/r/hnuvlQorQl

Answer (score 0):

Here, if none matches "dev" on one line

```
// for each line input    
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"dev", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);     
if (!match.Success) {       
// here you have non matching     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    string[] array = { "first.last@mail.mydomain.com", "firstLast@mail.mydomain.com", "name@mail.mydomain.com", "dev.test@mail.mydomain.com", "dev@mail.mydomain.com", "anytextherethatdoesNOTcontainDEVString@mail.mydomain.com" };
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?is)^(?!.*?dev).+@mail\.mydomain\.com$");
    foreach (string s in array)
        Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to determine if 'dev' appears anywhere in those strings:

```cs
var addresses = new[] {
    "first.last@mail.mydomain.com",
    "DeV.test@mail.mydomain.com",
    "first.last@dev.mydomain.com"
};
foreach(var address in addresses)
{
    // unfortunately C#'s String.Contains does not have an ignore case option
    // hack to use indexOf instead (which does provide such an option)
    var hasDev = (address.IndexOf("dev", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} contains dev: {1}", address, hasDev);
}
```

**Output**

```
first.last@mail.mydomain.com contains dev: false
DeV.test@mail.mydomain.com contains dev: true
first.last@dev.mydomain.com contains dev: true
```

---

Alternatively, if you only want to check the part of the address to the left of the '@', using a simple regular expression with `Regex.IsMatch()` would work:

```cs
var addresses = new[] {
    "first.last@mail.mydomain.com",
    "DeV.test@mail.mydomain.com",
    "first.last@dev.mydomain.com"
};
var pattern = @"dev.*@";
foreach(var address in addresses)
{
    var hasDevOnLeft = Regex.IsMatch(address, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} matches: {1}", address, hasDevOnLeft);
}
```

**Output**

```
first.last@mail.mydomain.com matches: false
DeV.test@mail.mydomain.com matches: true
first.last@dev.mydomain.com matches: false
```